# AngularJS Radio group not setting $dirty on field

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to use Angular's $dirty flag to submit only the changed fields in a form.

When I ran into radio button groups, I was missing the changes in the list of changed fields. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBY72/1/) that reproduces the problem I am seeing.

```
<div ng-app="form-example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="form" novalidate>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="myRadio" value="one" required>One<br />
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="myRadio" value="two" required>Two<br />
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="myRadio" value="three" required>Three<br />
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="myRadio" value="four" required>Four<br />
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="myRadio" value="five" required>Five<br /><br />
       Form $dirty: {{form.$dirty}}<br />
       Field $dirty: {{form.myRadio.$dirty}}<br />
       Value: {{myRadio}}
    </form>
</div>
```

The field's $dirty flag will only change when the last radio button is clicked even though the form $dirty updates properly.

Am I missing something fundamental here? and is there a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: Does the novalidate attribute have anything to do with the FormController not setting input states?

Comment: I've tried both with and without, novalidate just disables HTML5 validation, and only on submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `ng-model` actually instantiates a controller. 
When you click any radio button, the controller sets `$dirty` field to `true` and sets `form.$dirty` to true.

The problem is that `form.myRadio` holds the reference to the **last radio button's model**.

As a workaround you can use **nested forms** with `ng-form`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UM578/

Comment: Thanks Mr_Mig, and to anyone else with this issue, give the form the same name as your field, and change the inner input names (I appended .inner)

Answer (score 0):

I gave each radio input a unique name. Maybe you can give a broader view of what you are trying to do.

```
<div ng-app="form-example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio1" ng-model="myRadio" value="one" required>One<br />
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio2" ng-model="myRadio" value="two" required>Two<br />
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio3" ng-model="myRadio" value="three" required>Three<br />
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio4" ng-model="myRadio" value="four" required>Four<br />
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio5" ng-model="myRadio" value="five" required>Five<br /><br />
   Form $dirty: {{form.$dirty}}<br />
   Field 1 $dirty: {{form.myRadio1.$dirty}}<br />
   Field 2 $dirty: {{form.myRadio2.$dirty}}<br />
   Field 3 $dirty: {{form.myRadio3.$dirty}}<br />
   Field 4 $dirty: {{form.myRadio4.$dirty}}<br />
   Field 5 $dirty: {{form.myRadio5.$dirty}}<br />
   Value: {{myRadio}}
</form>
```

Comment: I'm trying to automate the collection of the dirty elements in a form, and having HTML names different than the model's name means I can't directly check that the whole group's value has changed with (formName[fieldName].$dirty).

Comment: The only thing I can think to work around this is check against what the value of $scope.myRadio rather than checking against $dirty = true  from each input.