# How do I make dynamically created radio buttons required - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with varying amount of rows.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Select Supervisor</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employeeInfo in employees" class="ng-cloak text-center">
            <td>{{employeeInfo.name}} {{employeeInfo.lastname}}</td>
            <td>
                <label><input type="radio" ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="true" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Approve</label>
                <label><input type="radio" ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="false" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Reject</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <a id="Approve" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="approveSupervisorChanges()">Submit</a>
</div>
```

One of the columns contain radio buttons "Approve" & "Reject"

How do I make it a requirement that in all rows the user has to have selected a radio button before he can submit ?

I tried this solution [Validate Radio Button AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685664/validate-radio-button-angularjs) by adding

```
ng-required="!employeeInfo.attributes[0].value"
```

But then it seems that accepted is a requirement, and if rejected is selected I can't submit

Comment: Note It's a user requirement that nothing is selected by default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Radio Button AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685664/validate-radio-button-angularjs)

Comment: I would create buttons for approve and inject instead of one submit button and radio buttons. FWIW: There's a `required` attribute for `input` elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can put required attribute simply like:

```
<label><input type="radio" required ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="true" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Approve</label>
            <label><input type="radio" required ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="false" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Reject</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got it working using by using ng-required like this.

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-required="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="true" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Approve</label>
<label><input type="radio" ng-required="!employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-model="employeeInfo.attributes[0].value" ng-value="false" ng-change="updateEmployeeAttribute(employeeInfo)">Reject</label>
```

Which isn't really perfect(but it works) as when noting is selected, a popup highlights only the reject radio button and says "Please select one of these options"