# Angular nested ng-form causes $modelValue to not be set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, nested

I'm having a little issue with an Angular project. Firstly the $digest value in a form wasn't set to true, in certain conditions. I fixed it via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052729/angularjs-radio-group-not-setting-dirty-on-field).

So in order to fix that problem I had to put a ng-form around some parts in my form. Making it look like the following:

```
<div class="fim-sub-input">
    <ng-form name="gender" novalidate>
        <label class="fim-radio" fim-radio ng-repeat="gender in genders">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{ gender.id }}" ng-model="card.gender">
            <span class="fim-sub-label">{{ gender.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

This fixed my $digest problem. However now in the form, the gender property never has a $modelValue property? All other form properties still do, except the gender property, which is in a nested form doesn't have it. Is this expected behaviour?

I currently fixed it by setting the `form.gender.$modelValue` to the value which is in the scope's model, before I process the form. It works, but it's ugly :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are trying, but ng-model should be gender.gender instead of card.gender.

You might still eventually get some issues since you are using ng-repeat which creates a child scope (unless you use ng-model = $parent.gender.gender)